# Why is the make command giving errors and how to fix it?

Tags: gcc, lemur

I have to use this program Lemur for some h.w but i am having troubles installing it as I have never used Linux. I downloaded cygwin and ran the ./configure which seemingly runs fine.
When I try the make command I'm coming across some issues which I have a hard time interpreting, even after looking around in supposed similar questions.
[image: make error on cygwin with Lemur toolkit]

Needless to say this causes problems when I try the make install command later on.

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't a make problem.  Your code is trying to call a function `computeHash` which is not defined.  Likely this means that you've forgotten to `#include` some header file, but it could be something else.  Find the `.h` file where `computeHash()` is declared and include it.  Since you don't have any errors about files not being found by the compiler, it doesn't seem like a problem of missing/not installed software.

Comment: Any ideas on how may i find this function? Also, where should i add this include it?

Comment: You can search through the header files to find one that declares it.  Once found, add the include to the source files that fail to compile.  We can't help with this: this is a question related to that particular codebase, not a general problem with makefiles, linux, programming, or whatever.  You need to ask someone who knows something about that code.

Answer (score 0):

The Lemur code relies on some quirks of the version of gcc/C++ standard it was built for (g++ 4.4, I believe).

These are the changes I needed to make lemur-4.12 under gcc 7.4. This isn't based on any deep understanding of the Lemur code; I'm just logging the changes as I make them:

**Most of the changes just require adding explicit casts or `this->`s**

utility/include/CSet.hpp:63  `int idx = this->operator=[](u);`

utility/include/ISet.hpp:90  `int hashval = this->computeHash(u);`

utility/include/ISet.hpp:104 `const int hashval = this->computeHash(sn->u);`

utility/include/ISet.hpp:105 `typename PSet<ObjType>::SET_NODE *snNew = this->createNode(sn->u);`

utility/include/ISet.hpp:109 `this->deleteNode(sn);`

retrieval/src/ResultFile.cpp:134 `return (bool)(*inStr >> curQID >> dummy1 >> curDID >> dummy2 >> curSC >> dummy3);`

retrieval/src/ResultFile.cpp:136 `return (bool)(*inStr >> curQID >> curDID >> curSC);`

utility/src/BasicDocStream.cpp:78 `moreDoc = (bool)(*ifs >> buf);`

**Was comparing a non-pointer to NULL. Fortunately, they commented about what they were trying to do.**

utility/src/WordSet.cpp:42 `if (ifstr.fail()) {`

**For these two, they were returning `false` as a pointer; `(bool)NULL` is false, so `NULL` is *probably* what they meant.**

utility/src/BulkTree.cpp:571 `return NULL;`

utility/src/BulkTree.cpp:587 `return NULL;`

**This one's just a bug. They were comparing a pointer to the NUL *character*. I suspect they meant to compare the character it pointed to to NUL, but since it should probably stop reading if either c == NULL *or* *c == '\0', I just made it check for both.**

parsing/src/OffsetAnnotationAnnotator.cpp:194  `for ( const char* c = str; i < n && c && *c != '\0'; c++, i++ )`

**You need to run `make` twice for it to build everything. Not sure why.**

---

I also recommend setting `export CXXFLAGS='-Wno-write-strings -Wno-deprecated` before running `configure`. There are too many warnings of those types to fix them all, and they're potentially hiding more critical warnings.  Which reveals:

**Possible issue: That \0 doesn't do get stored in qChar; it just terminates the format string. I'm leaving it alone for now, since that would *never* have worked differently no matter the version of gcc, so the code that uses qChar probably doesn't need the extra \0 to be there.**

site-search/cgi/DBInterface.cpp:628 `sprintf(qChar, "#q1=%s\0", query.c_str());`

**They were using the wrong format specifier for size_t**

site-search/cgi/IndriSearchInterface.cpp:815 `fprintf(oQueryLog, "(%lu results)\n", (unsigned long)finalResults.size());`

---

Note that these are just the changes needed to make it *compile*.  It's entirely possible that it also depends on undefined behavior behaving the way it did under gcc 5.4. I'd definitely recommend turning on --enable-assert when running `configure`.